# Error when using npm install after cloning a repo from github into a new computer

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I cloned my repository with react project to a new computer. I installed node.js, npm, brew and python. I already tried few things and still, I cannot perform **npm install** command. I get the following error:

````
npm ERR! path /Users/kasia/Desktop/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/kasia/Desktop/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/kasia/Desktop/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /Users/kasia/.pyenv/shims/python2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/kasia/.pyenv/shims/python2 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack pyenv: python2: command not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack The `python2' command exists in these Python versions:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack       python2 and python3 to be found.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/kasia/Desktop/portfolio/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kasia/Desktop/portfolio/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/kasia/.npm/_logs/2024-02-26T21_48_02_289Z-debug-0.log
kasia@Katarzynas-MacBook-Air portfolio % python --version```

Could you please help me solve this error?
````

Comment: Means that npm unsuccessfully tries to compile node-sass instead of using precompiled version. node-sass is tied to specific version it's compatible with. Downgrade node to the  version the project has been developed with